# How can I repeat each row of a BigQuery table multiple times?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to repeat each row in my BigQuery table 10 times (so that I can see how my query will perform if my table gets 10x bigger). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays and a cross join:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ds.larger_table AS

WITH orig AS (
  SELECT * FROM ds.small_table
)
SELECT orig.*
FROM 
   orig,
   UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10)) AS repeat_number
```

If the original table is partitioned and/or clustered, make sure to also partition the larger table.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter answer than Lak's, because why not:

```
SELECT orig.* 
FROM orig, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10))
```

This is:

- Instead of `*` use `orig.*` to avoid the need to do an `EXCEPT()`.
- The `UNNEST` then doesn't need to name the `repeat_number`.

Comment: good point. edited!  I kept the repeat_number because ... readability